# Bootstrap 3 grid system - "cells" are expandable in height, but it shifts the entire next row down

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this page where you click on a text block, the box opens comments below it. The row below it shifts down then. Problem is that ALL columns in the row below shift down, which creates a ton of whitespace.Only 1 should shift down (the one below the expanded cell). Is there a way to do this with bootstrap 3?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to change the layout of your grid. you wouldn't lay them out 3 across to a row, you would lay them out going down in columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="idea-block"> ... </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="comment-area"> ... </div>

        <div class="idea-block"> ... </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="comment-area"> ... </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="idea-block"> ... </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="comment-area"> ... </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="idea-block"> ... </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="comment-area"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                [here's where to put the picture of  
                the car spanning 2 columns, so  to speak]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="idea-block"> ... </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="comment-area"> ... </div>

        <div class="idea-block"> ... </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="comment-area"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sense?

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: @user2475825 I edited the example above to clarify. I tested it locally and it works fine. HTH :)

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm! I wish I could upvote your answer, but I need 15 rep points here on SO. Thanks.